# MySql - What could cause FOUND_ROWS() to return an incorrect value?

Tags: mysql

I have a query similar to the example below (only column names changed for this post), that returns a paged selection of records from a MySql database using LIMIT, plus the count of records that would have been returned were the limit not applied via FOUND_ROWS().

In the case below SELECT FOUND_ROWS() simply returns 10, although I know that the query returns more rows if the limit is removed. I also have this working as I would expect for many several other very similar queries.

What could cause MySql to return an unexpected value that might explain what I'm seeing here?

```
SELECT 
id, 
firstname, 
surname, 
'' as anothercolumn1, 
date as anothercolumn2, 
'literal' as db 

FROM some_table 

WHERE 
filter_col LIKE @val1 
and surname LIKE @val2 
ORDER BY surname, firstname 
LIMIT 0, 10; 

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` after the 1st `SELECT` keyword in order to get accurate result when you call `FOUNC_ROWS()`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
id,
firstname,
...

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: Thanks, the documentation also makes reference to slightly more complex use with UNION statements which is applicable in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) in your query:

```
SELECT 
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
id, 
firstname, 
....
```